# Type Mismatch when comparing value from an InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

I think my code is ok, but it shows type mismatch after I run it, can someone please help?
(The type mismatch is from the gender part)

```
Sub tuitioncal()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Gender As String
    Dim LocalID As String
    Dim CreditUD As Integer
    Dim GenderAbb As String
    Dim tuitionFee As Double
    Dim uniFee As Double
    Dim totalFee As Double
    Name = InputBox("Enter your FULL name:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    Gender = InputBox("Enter your gender: Male/Female", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    LocalID = InputBox("Enter your status: Local or Non-Local", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    CreditUD = InputBox("Enter the total numbers of credits you are taking:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
        If Gender = "Female" Or "F" Then
            GenderAbb = "Ms."
        ElseIf Gender = "Male" Or "M" Then
            GenderAbb = "Mr."
        End If
    'some code afterwards
```

---

Thanks everyone! I have completed my code now, yet I still face difficulties in running the program, any suggestions?

```
    Option Explicit
Sub tuitioncal()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Gender As Variant
    Dim LocalID As String
    Dim CreditUD As Integer
    Dim sCreditUD As String
    Dim GenderAbb As String
    Dim tuitionFee As Double
    Dim uniFee As Double
    Dim totalFee As Double
    Name = InputBox("Enter your FULL name:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    Gender = InputBox("Enter your gender: Male/Female", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    LocalID = InputBox("Enter your status: Local or Non-Local", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    sCredit = InputBox("Enter the total numbers of credits you are taking:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    If Not IsNumeric(sCredit) Then
        MsgBox sCredit & " is not a numeric value. Aborting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CreditUD = Int(sCredit)
        If Gender = "Female" Or Gender = "F" Then
            GenderAbb = "Ms."
        ElseIf Gender = "Male" Or Gender = "M" Then
            GenderAbb = "Mr."
        End If
    Do While LocalID = "Local"
        If CreditUD >= 8 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050 / 2
        ElseIf CreditUD > 8 And CreditUD <= 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050
        ElseIf CreditUD > 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050 + (CreditUD - 21) * 2670
        End If
    Loop
    Do While LocalID = "Non-Local"
        If CreditUD >= 12 And CreditUD <= 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 60000
        ElseIf CreditUD > 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 60000 + (CreditUD - 21) * 4030
        End If
    Loop

uniFee = 400 + CreditUD * 50
totalFee = uniFee + tuitionFee
tuitionFee = Format(tuitionFee, "$#####.00")
uniFee = Format(uniFee, "$#####.00")
totalFee = Format(totalFee, "$#####.00")

MsgBox GenderAbb & Name & "," & VBA.vbCrLf & VBA.vbCrLf & "Based on your inputs - " _
& LocalID & "student and" & CreditUD & "credits:" & VBA.vbCrLf & VBA.vbCrLf & _
"Your tuition fee is" & tuitionFee & VBA.vbCrLf & "Your university fees is" & uniFee & _
VBA.vbCrLf & "Your Total fees is" & totalFee
End Sub
```

Is there anything I can improve the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If statement do not work like you think they do. Each part of it needs its own full comparison.

In other words, your If statement should look like this

```
    If Gender = "Female" Or Gender = "F" Then
        GenderAbb = "Ms."
    ElseIf Gender = "Male" Or Gender = "M" Then
        GenderAbb = "Mr."
    End If
```

The reason for the type mismatch is that it's expecting a `Boolean` (True/False) for each part of the `If` (separated by your `Or`) - and `"F"` all by itself is not a `Boolean` value, it's a `String` value.

You may also run into issue if the user enters a non-numeric value into `CreditUD` as you defined it as an `Integer`, and `InputBox` always returns a `String`.

To address that:

```
Dim sCreditUD As String
Dim CreditUD As Integer

sCreditUD = InputBox("Enter the total numbers of credits you are taking:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
If Not IsNumeric(sCreditUD) Then
  MsgBox sCreditUD & " is not a numeric value. Aborting."
  Exit Sub
End If
CreditUD = Int(sCreditUD)
```

Comment: It is incorrect to say that Input box always return string. It returns a variant. The content allowed in the variant is defined by the optional Type parameter. The default type is string.

Comment: That is only if you use `Application.InputBox` instead of `InputBox`, and the OP is not using `Application.InputBox`

Comment: Then perhaps we should be guiding the OP towards using Application.InputBox

Comment: If that was what the question was about, then "we" could surely do that.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply. I have finished the rest of my code now, yet it still cannot run. Please take a look at what I can improve, thank you so much guys!

Comment: Change `sCredit` to `sCreditUD` (in all 4 places) (my bad)

Comment: You are using `Option Explicit` so the program tells you exactly where the problem is...

Comment: Hi Mr braX, I have completed my code and corrected the code according to your suggestion, but I still cannot run the program, please help! Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly is the problem now? "cannot run the program" doesn't tell anyone anything.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the code in the question above, but the program stuck and no response after I run the program. It seems there is something wrong in the loop, so it looped infinitely after I enter numbers and answers to the input box. Can you please take a look at it? (Really sorry that I asked stupid questions and not stating the questions clearly.)

Comment: I see. So this has nothing to do with your original question. Please limit your questions to one per topic. Keep in mind that these questions are intended to also help others, and are not to be treated as your own personal help topic for any issue you run into while developing a program. I will provide another comment to help, but please start a new topic if you have a new question.

Comment: `Do While LocalID = "Non-Local"` - this condition never changes inside of your loop, so of course it's going to run infinitely. Rethink why you are using a loop in the first place, and keep in mind if you need help with this unrelated item, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Option Explicit
Sub tuitioncal()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Gender As Variant
    Dim LocalID As String
    Dim CreditUD As Integer
    Dim sCreditUD As String
    Dim GenderAbb As String
    Dim tuitionFee As Double
    Dim uniFee As Double
    Dim totalFee As Double
    Name = InputBox("Enter your FULL name:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    Gender = InputBox("Enter your gender: Male/Female", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    LocalID = InputBox("Enter your status: Local or Non-Local", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    sCredit = InputBox("Enter the total numbers of credits you are taking:", "Tuition & Fees Calculator")
    If Not IsNumeric(sCredit) Then
        MsgBox sCredit & " is not a numeric value. Aborting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    CreditUD = Int(sCredit)
        If Gender = "Female" Or Gender = "F" Then
            GenderAbb = "Ms."
        ElseIf Gender = "Male" Or Gender = "M" Then
            GenderAbb = "Mr."
        End If
    Do While LocalID = "Local"
        If CreditUD >= 8 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050 / 2
        ElseIf CreditUD > 8 And CreditUD <= 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050
        ElseIf CreditUD > 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 21050 + (CreditUD - 21) * 2670
        End If
    Loop
    Do While LocalID = "Non-Local"
        If CreditUD >= 12 And CreditUD <= 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 60000
        ElseIf CreditUD > 21 Then
            tuitionFee = 60000 + (CreditUD - 21) * 4030
        End If
    Loop

uniFee = 400 + CreditUD * 50
totalFee = uniFee + tuitionFee
tuitionFee = Format(tuitionFee, "$#####.00")
uniFee = Format(uniFee, "$#####.00")
totalFee = Format(totalFee, "$#####.00")

MsgBox GenderAbb & Name & "," & VBA.vbCrLf & VBA.vbCrLf & "Based on your inputs - " _
& LocalID & "student and" & CreditUD & "credits:" & VBA.vbCrLf & VBA.vbCrLf & _
"Your tuition fee is" & tuitionFee & VBA.vbCrLf & "Your university fees is" & uniFee & _
VBA.vbCrLf & "Your Total fees is" & totalFee
End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone please check the code for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not post additional questions as answers. Instead, you can add things like this to your question by editing it.